# Finding data on (estimated) trade cost elasticities of imports

Tags: international-trade, elasticity, united-kingdom

I'm an undergrad student of economics, and I need to find estimates of the trade cost elasticity of the UK's imports for some homework. My instructors pointed me to the World Bank's databases, specifically the [World Development Indicators](https://databank.worldbank.org/source/world-development-indicators), but I've not been able to find those estimates there. Google has not proved helpful either.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question --- although I don't have a a reference per se, I've been told that

1. if you have no idea at all, -5 is a good ,,first guess``, and
2. there is a paper (and this is what I don't have a reference for, sadly) where the author worked through all the available estimates and arrived at -4,25 as the ,,best guess``.